# Installing pypiwin32 successful; cannot import module

Tags: python-3.x, pypi

Title says it all;

Tried typical cmd commands like:

```
pip install pypiwin32
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

Python script:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install("pypiwin32") # also tried 'pywin32'
```

I run the above script and get the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in 'path'
```

Then run test command:

```
import pypiwin32
```

and get:

```
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypiwin32'
```

Is there something wrong with my path? Do i HAVE to install it as a .whl file?

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am wanting a module to convert text to speech.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, not sure if i should answer my own question or delete this, but it may help someone in the future.

I went into my python path and checked my .pyd files, it turns out there was no module called pypiwin32. instead the module is called win32com.pyd

So using the following code:

```
import win32com.client as wincl
wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak("Speak English, parle français")
```

Comment: Doesn't speak French aparently, hahaha :P.